# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.ipl.model.User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one REST Call as

```
List<User> userList = (List<User>) iplUtil.getResult(user, mongoGetURL);

System.out.println("userList === "+userList);
```

output as

```
 userList = [{_id={$oid=571903dae4b085317593a0d3}, nickName=aa, email=aa, password=aa, userId=1}]
```

No complile time error..
but this line failing in runtime

```
User u =userList.get(0);
```

getting exception at this line as

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.ipl.model.User
```

and model as

```
package com.ipl.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, String> _id;
    private String nickName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private int userId;


    public User(String nickName,String password) {
        this.nickName=nickName;
        this.password=password;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public Map<String, String> get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(Map<String, String> _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [_id=" + _id + ", nickName=" + nickName + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password
                + ", userId=" + userId + "]";
    }

}
```

Im not getting any complie time error..why its failing in runtime

Comment: If you can't submit the question because you have too little text besides the source code, it probably means you should add more detail, keep that in mind.

Comment: I don't know what `iplUtil.getResult` is, but you're probably trying to deserialiaze something without providing the appropriate type.

Comment: If `iplUtil.getResult` just returns the json object you wouldn't be able to cast it to list of users. You would need an [object mapper](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: if thats the case why Im not getting compilation error...why it is able cast to List<User> without any compile time error

Comment: whats the signature of `iplUtil.getResult` method?

Comment: Object..public Object getResult(Object parameters, String url) {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  try {
   ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url,
     Object.class, convertObjectToString(parameters));
   System.out.println("response === " + response.getBody());
   return response.getBody();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   return "";
  }
 }

Comment: public String convertObjectToString(Object object) {
  
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
    Object json = objectMapper.readValue(
      objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object), Object.class);
    return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
      .writeValueAsString(json);
   } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  return "";
 }

Comment: the compiler would complain if you remove the cast. Casting the returned value to list is you assuring the compiler that you know that the returned object would be a list. But on runtime, if the value return by getResult method is not a list of users, then it fails. Checkout [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for a better understanding of casting.

Comment: got it thxs..its returning list of map..which is raw type...